# How to improve this ruby code more idiomatic?

Tags: ruby

Since the code below looks very old fashion and ugly. But after playing around this way is only working.

```
def duplicated? url
  found = false
  current_user.bookmarks.each do |bookmark|
    if bookmark.url.eql? url
      found = true
    end
  end
  found
end
```

I eliminated the local var found and the if statement like this

```
def duplicated? url
  current_user.bookmarks.each do |bookmark|
    bookmark.url.eql? url
  end
end
```

And it returns wrong expected result.

Any idea how to improve it ? Thanks

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) here. It should be preferred to map/include pair, because it doesn't create a temp array and it returns early on first element found.

```
def duplicated? url
  current_user.bookmarks.any?{|b| b.url.eql? url }
end
```

Comment: Fair enough. I missed the part where bookmarks weren't url, so include was the first that came to mind. I +1:ed your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
def duplicated?(url)
   current_user.bookmarks.map{|bm| bm.url}.include?(url)
end
```

Comment: Why have you posted this? It duplicates the answer of Jean-Louis Giordano.

Comment: I posted this when he hadn't done the map(), his answer was incorrect at the time. Also, I map explicitely which is faster because map(&:...) induces a cast that can quickly become a problem.

Comment: Althought I doubt that "it can quickly become a problem". I have never encountered this problem in practice.

Comment: I never had a single problem with `to_proc` and for me code readability is more important than performance (otherwise, why choose ruby?). So I'd say this is purely a matter of taste.

Comment: @Jean-LouisGiordano Indeed, then again it's good to know there is a choice.